# iPhone iCloud contacts and over the air sync

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, icloud

As I understand, the "over the air sync" is different from iCloud sync (for the contacts). Is it the case?

Is the over the air sync just a sync with my Mac itself? So it is just an cordless version of the iTunes sync?

Comment: No, "over the air" would imply they are synced through iCloud. Do you have any reason to believe this is not working as expected?

Comment: I've not used wifi (I assume this is what you mean by "over the air") sync with my iPad and iPhone but as I understand it, it's a replacement for cable sync with iTunes.

Comment: @Gerry: I don't think they are sync through iCloud as I didn't put my contacts on iCloud (it's just the old plain storage on my mbp - that's because I also sync with google but that's another issue).

Comment: @CedricH. I should rephrase that. If you see 'over the air' in the "Info" tab in iTunes, it indicates they are synced through an online service like iCloud or Google Sync. Could you clarify if this is what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: the iCloud sync sends data to and from the iCloud servers, and the Wi-Fi sync sends data to and from your computer running iTunes.